# How to approach my company about software made in my spare time that can help with our process

Tags: software-industry, france

As a software developer there is many part of my job that can be tedious and/or time consuming. Whenever it is possible I create scripts or softwares to make it easier on me, or make the process fully automated.

Usually it's softwares that anyone could make in a few hours, so I don't publish them anywhere, as there is no point. 
But I've recently started to work on a software wich can drastically reduces the amount of work needed when it comes to our database.

Basically my software is a script editor wich automatically implement every process we're supposed to take into account when creating a script. The script is formatted in a company-specific way, every needed verification needed is automatically performed.

So my question would be, in what way could I present this software to my team/company ? I am afraid that his may be seen as a gadget/novelty, and end up not being used / adopted by the company.

If it is helpful, we're situated in France, and we're working with the Agile method. In-house software to help with tedious processes are not uncommon here, but are usually done on command by the company.

**Note :** 
To be clear, I am not trying to sell this software to them, but to give them the rights and sources of the soft, so that other people can use it, and develop it further.
I tried searching for similar questions, but every questions I found where about selling a software.

Comment: What's the downside for it not getting adopted by your company? Could you still use it for yourself if they don't adopt it? Has it been created fully in your spare time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's tools that you developed to make your own job easier, I'd absolutely encourage you to share it with your co-workers.  Sometimes just pushing the scripts to a side repo, putting them on a file share, or corporate file sharing account is all that's needed.  Then email everyone the link with a description of what it does.  Something like the following:

> Team:
>
> Like many of you, I continually am going through redundant cycle of
>   building, deploying, debugging, and pulling down logs for analysis,
>   then running the parse tool on the logs to find the output of my
>   relevant sections of code.  This overhead easily takes 5 minutes per
>   iteration regardless of how much code I changed.
>
> And I do it 10 times
>   a day. So I wrote a script that makes it easier and does all the work
>   for you.  So now this overhead is reduced to 1 minute.    You can find
>   the script in your enlistment at tools/scripts/debugstuff.  Just edit
>   the headers at the top of the script with your test account password
>   and test machine IP address.  See the comments at the top of the file.
>   Let me know if you have any questions or suggestions.
>
> user3399

Stuff like this not only makes your team more efficient, it creates a great culture and motivates others on the team to do the same and/or improve your work, or offer suggestions back.  There's really no downside to sharing stuff with co-workers to make their life easier.

Comment: This is closest to the answer that I would give. Let me add that some companies will want the scripts to be *documented* and/or *controlled* (released into a version control system). I wrote a tool using *code* at home. When I went to share it, I was told that it needed to be documented and controlled. I said that I wouldn't do that for free. They funded a small project to make my tool *official*. It never got the widespread use that I expected, but a few people use it all the time and think that it is great. Scripts may have lower requirements for documentation, it depends on the company.

Comment: Yes, some companies probably have process and guidelines.  Most places will just defer to the teams themselves to manage and maintain their own locally sourced tools.

Comment: @selbie, depending on how many people on the project but if tool is getting used by few people it is still the worth to approach the manager or people who manage source control for the team to put it in source control. Disk space is dirt cheap today, time you would loose if the tool vanishes is not. Basically you can use this argument when you approach a manager. If you pay per repo you can create a repository for all tools and then add a separate folder for each tool. And the easiest way to have documentation is to create Readme.md in the tools root.

Comment: @AlexanderM - Good stuff there, no doubt. But it was not a goal of my answer to describe *how* to publish a tool.   The answer is strong encouragement to the OP that they should not be fearful of sharing code. But yeah, respect the processes and best practices of your teams, and make it easy to consume.   As a manager, I'm always encouraging my team to contribute to making the engineering environment better. And when they do, there might be a quick discussion of which repo, folder, or packaging tool to use, but that's a 5 second conversation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good template for pitching new ideas that's worked incredibly well for me in the past.  It has three parts:

**Describe the current situation.**  Basically, what's the current process that's being followed.

**List the downsides of that approach.**  Why would someone want to improve the process, what are the pain-points, etc.

**Demonstrate an alternative.**  Describe - or ideally show - an alternative way of doing the process that solves some of the downsides described in the second step.

This is an easy-to-grok format.  It gives the background info needed to make an informed decision on the topic.  It demonstrates a business use.  And it gives the manager a good position to decide whether your proposal is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, **the intellectual property rights for this *probably* already belong to your employer**, even if you wrote this in your spare time. Check out L113-9 of the Intellectual Property Code in French law. It sounds like you created this in your spare time but in the course of your duties.

> in what way could I present this software to my team/company ?

**Demonstrate your automation**; find the right forum and show people how it helps. If your colleagues see it work, some of them will want to try it.

In my experience, **software engineers create this kind of automation all the time**, and it is very much a part of how we work. Depending on your colleagues there could be some scepticism or resentment, but mainly people like things that make life better/easier and aren't hard to maintain.

To your manager:

```
"I took initiative and created some software that will help us become more productive."
```

Don't be shy - you've done something good, and any manager worth their salt will recognise and encourage that. Maybe next time you will be allowed to carve out time from your working day to do this kind of work...

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote it, and it is related to your job, you should assume they have complete ownership rights to it. This is the standard employment agreement for software developers.

Comment: If I write some code at home and it **could** be applied to work you are suggesting it will automatically belong to the company?

Comment: @SolarMike: It depends on the exact legal agreement you signed, but often it works exactly as Julie said.

Comment: @BenVoigt So they pay for 8 hours a day but take 24...

Comment: @SolarMike: Knowledge workers are usually paid salary, not hourly.  So there is no such thing as "pay for 8 hours a day".  I am lucky enough to have an employer that compensates overtime for salaried employees, but it's rare.

Comment: @BenVoigt - I've never heard of a salaried worker being paid for overtime. The only "compensation" I've heard of is additional time off -- "comp time". How does that work? Is there an "overtime after 40 + X hours"?

Comment: @JulieinAustin: We fill out timesheets like hourly employees (needed anyway for contract billing), and anything over 80 (in two weeks) shows up as non-salary work on our paystub.  It's paid at 1.0X not 1.5X but still a great deal because most other employers would just say those additional hours are part of being salaried.

Comment: @BenVoigt - What happens, other than getting fired ( ;) ) if you consistently have less than 80 hours every two weeks? And yes, that's a great deal -- during my time at a Very Big Company I think I averaged 55 hours a week during one multi-year stretch.

Comment: @JulieinAustin: If you have fewer than 80 hours of work time on a pay period, you consume PTO.  If you run out of that, time for a conversation with the boss about unpaid time off or being part time (for example, I was consistently under 80 hours for an extended period of time while writing my dissertation).  Yes it's a great deal for the engineers, but it's also a fantastic deal for the company -- they have more contract-billable hours per month and projects are more likely to finish ahead of schedule, which at least raises client happiness and may also trigger bonus clauses.

Comment: @BenVoigt - I'll admit it's a great deal, but that sounds like some kind of hourly employment arrangement, but without the 1.5x pay rate. And yes, I'd like to get paid for all the over-40-hours I work, but I've not been a billable employee in almost 30 years, and even then I mostly was never billed.

Comment: @JulieinAustin: There's a lot that is peculiar in my employer's business model, and the various pieces wouldn't necessarily work well in isolation.

Comment: @JulieinAustin it does not work like that in France, at least not according to any contract I every signed. Anything I make on my own spare time belong to me, and me only, my employer has no right to it, unless I use company ressources to do it.

Comment: @user3399 - I'm not as up on French employment law as I should be to go running off and answering this question. That said, the multinational companies I'm familiar with would assert that if it is job-related, it is theirs because it's impossible to do work which is "job related" without the benefit of that job. In this particular case, you are "testing" your software "on company time", if only because you're using it "on company time". And if you start telling people about it, you're advertising it "on company time". See the problem?

Comment: @JulieinAustin Anyway, that's not the problem, as I said on my post, I don't plan on selling it to them, I just want to maximize the chances of the software being given a fair short. I plan on giving the right, and sources of the software to them anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Is it something that helps a developer in his day-to-day work (e.g. An IDE plugin) ? In that case, simply share your tool through an email or in a learn-and-share moment if your team organizes these. Make sure to clearly explain why it's helpful - if it really is, you will have no difficulties in getting your colleagues to use it.

If it is something that helps the company/user (e.g. Something that makes it easier to avoid bugs and therefore create better software and bring in more revenue), you should probably talk to your manager instead. In that case they will make sure in your place that it's used everywhere.